# What does Django do when a request to the root comes?

Tags: python, django

I am programming a django web app. I don't understand how it works concurrently. Basically, what happens is that I have a page that takes 10 seconds to load (due to a lot of python computation being executed), and another page that takes about 1 second to load due to less python code to execute and immediately returning the index.html page. 
This is the link that I provided in the routing.

localhost:3000/10secondpage

localhost:3000/1secondpage

I perform this action on my browser: 
Open first browser to localhost:3000/10secondpage, then immediately open a second browser to localhost:3000/1secondpage

As I am only running it on localhost with 1 terminal, this was the behavior I expected.

Expected Behavior: 
The python code executes the first browser's request and takes 10 second to complete, after it is done, it immediately starts the second browser's request and takes about 1 second to complete. As a result, the second browser needs to wait about 11 seconds in total as it needs to wait for the first browser's request to be completed first.

Actual Behavior:
However, the actual behaviour was that the second browser completed its request first despite being execute after the first browser. This suggest django comes with some built in process/thread spawning already.

Can someone please explain why does the actual behavior occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put simple, its threading.

Web requests do not depend on other requests to be able to be finished before you are able to execute your request, if it did, then posting an update to facebook would take hours/months/years before your post actually makes it live.

Django is no different. In order to process any number of requests that a page may receive at once, it must process them individually and asyncronously. Of course, this can become much more complex very quickly with the introduction of load sharing and similar but it comes down to the same answer.

You can take a look at the [Handlers source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/core/handlers) to see more in detail about what django does with this

---

Note: I haven't tried this but to observe your expected output you can run `runserver` with the [`--nothreading`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---nothreading) flag

```
 manage.py runserver --nothreading
```

Comment: Note that with the exception of the development server, this has nothing to do with Django: it's the webserver itself - Apache, nginx or whatever - that deals with the multiple threads/processes.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Agreed, thanks. In my small attempt to keep it to a very minimal example i think I missed out that point :)